# requirejs, babelify and browserify when npm installing and building a module

Tags: javascript, requirejs, npm, browserify

I have a problem with an npm module I've created. It's built using browserify and babelify.

Here is a snippet from the `package.json`:

```
"name": "foo",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "watchify src/foo.js -t babelify -s foo -o ./index.js"
}
```

Which is basically the entire build process (no minifying or anything). There are also some tests, which run without a problem.

In `src/foo.js` I import other files, which are located in the same folder.

```
import bar from './bar';
```

So, the file structure looks something like:

```
index.js
package.json
src/
    foo.js
    bar.js
```

Now, when I install the module elsewhere, in a completely different project, and `import` it:

```
import foo from 'foo';
```

... and build the new project with

```
watchify src/app.js -d -t babelify -o js/app.js
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './bar' from '[file_path]/node_modules/foo/'
```

So basically (as I understand it), it looks at the (now) `var bar = require('./bar');` and searches in the file path (the same folder) whereas, everything in reality was bundled into one file, everything included.

What am I missing here? How do I build it correctly?

Comment: I think there may be some confusion about paths here, if you have a npm module stored in you node_modules folder, you can simply reference it without './' so ```var bar = require('bar')``` if you want to reference a module within that folder, in this case 'foo.js' you would add the './' at the beginning ```var foo = require('./foo');```

Comment: Yes yes, that's what I'm doing. `foo.js` requires `'./bar.js'` (because it's in the same folder). But when I npm install the library somewhere else, then it's stored in node_modules, and I import it with just `import foo from 'foo';`